# Creating an array from named range

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to create few arrays from named range in my workbook instead of defining that arrays manually.

Example:
This is the array I want to create

Array("bardzo lekka", "lekka", "średnia", "ciężka")
The same data is definied in named range  `$A$5:$A$8`. I want to load that range into array like above.

I've tried to do this like that:

```
kategoria_a = ActiveWorkbook.Names("kategoria_agronomiczna_gleby").RefersToRange(1, 1)
```

It creates only one object array.

```
kategoria_a = ActiveWorkbook.Names("kategoria_agronomiczna_gleby")
```

That makes

```
kategoria_a = ='Dane wyjściowe'!$A$5:$A$8
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question, how to load all a workbook's named ranges into an array?

Comment: Please show an example with expected output

Comment: Your manually-created array contains strings, not named ranges. Your question is unclear.

Comment: I want to load array kategoria_a from named value. It's definied in range $A$5:$A$8. Sorry if I made unclear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your values are listed in along a column you could use:

```
kategoria_a = Application.Transpose(ActiveWorkbook.Names("kategoria_agronomiczna_gleby").RefersToRange.Value)
```

while if they are listed along a row then you could use

```
kategoria_a = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose(ActiveWorkbook.Names("kategoria_agronomiczna_gleby").RefersToRange.Value))
```

to obtain a 1D array

Comment: This is what I intended to do. Than you.

Comment: Prosze bardzo :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Dim a As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range, r As Range

a = Array("bardzo lekka", "lekka", "średnia", "ciężka")

For i = LBound(a) to UBound(a)
    If i = LBound(a) Then
        Set rng = Range(a(i))
    Else
        Set rng = Union(rng, a(i))
    End If
Next i
```

`a` contains all named ranges. To access the values you could use this:

```
For Each r In rng
    debug.print r.value
Next r
```

Comment: IMO this is most likely what OP is asking about - although, there's no way to be sure until they clarify their question.

Answer (score 0):

This will take all the named ranges, and put them in an array (`myArr`):

```
Sub get_named_ranges()
Dim rng As Range
Dim nm
Dim myArr() As Variant

ReDim myArr(1 To ThisWorkbook.Names.Count)

Dim i As Long
i = 1
For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
    myArr(i) = nm.Name
    i = i + 1
Next nm

For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)
    Debug.Print (myArr(i))
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to set an array equal to the values in a named range,instead of entering them manually (like your example), then just set the array equal to the range.  As long as "kategoria_agronomiczna_gleby" is your named range.

```
kategoria_a = ActiveWorkbook.Range("kategoria_agronomiczna_gleby")
```

You can use this loop to check the values in your array

```
 For i = LBound(kategoria_a, 1) To UBound(kategoria_a, 1)
    Debug.Print kategoria_a(i, 1)
  Next
```